# Heap sort heapify sort

Tags: c, sorting, heapsort

I have a problem witch Heap Sort. I don't know what is wrong in my code. This program changed only second and last position in a table. This is my code (without main function):

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#define DUZO 100000000
int heap_size;
int tab[DUZO];

void heapify(int start){
    int l, r, largest, pom;

    l = 2*start + 1;
    r = 2*start + 2;

    if((l < heap_size) && (tab[l] > tab[start]))
        largest = l;
    else
        largest = start;

    if((r <  heap_size) && (tab[r] > tab[largest]))
        largest = r;
    if(largest != start){
        pom = tab[start];
        tab[start] = tab[largest];
        tab[largest] = pom;

        heapify(largest);
    }
}

void build_max(){
    int lenght, i;
    lenght = heap_size;

    for(i = ((lenght - 1)/2); i >= 0; --i){
        heapify(i);
    }
}

void heap_sort(){
    int i;
    build_max();


    for(i = heap_size-1; i > 0; --i) {
        int tmp = tab[0];
        tab[0] = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tmp;
        --heap_size;
        heapify(0);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: It might help others reading this code if you were to go through it line-by-line adding comments explaining the *purpose* of each statement, loop, and function. In doing that, you may well find places where what the code actually does is not in agreement with what you intend it to do.

Comment: Why not just use one of the many existing heapsort implementations instead of trying to write your own?

Comment: Agreed, someone marked this for close in review.  I'll mark to leave it open, but you should add comments and show your output (with a small input data set) and provide a main so it's runnable without editing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int heap_size = 6;
int tab[5];
```

That's calling for writing (and reading) past the end of the array, causing undefined behaviour with probably bad consequences.

It's a bad idea to have the heap size and array as a global variables, they should be arguments to the functions.

```
l = 2*start + 1;
r = 2*start + 2;
```

That's the indexing for when you have the top of the heap at index 0, but

```
if((l <= heap_size) && (tab[l] > tab[start]))
```

that check would be used if you have the top of the heap at index 1. For index 0, that should be `<` (also in the next check for `r`).

```
void build_max(){
    int lenght, i;
    lenght = heap_size;

    for(i = ((lenght - 1)/2); i > 0; i--){
        heapify(i);
    }
}
```

forgets to heapify the top, so it doesn't in general create a heap, the condition should be `i >= 0`.

```
void heap_sort(){
    int i, lenght;
    build_max();
    lenght =  heap_size;

    for(i = lenght; i > 1; i--){
        heap_size -= 1;
        heapify(i);
    }
}
```

doesn't swap the top of the heap in the last position, so it doesn't sort at all. The loop should look like

```
for(i = heap_size-1; i > 0; --i) {
    /* swap top of heap in the last position */
    int tmp = tab[0];
    tab[0] = tab[i];
    tab[i] = tmp;
    --heap_size; /* urk, but what can we do if heapify uses the global? */
    heapify(0);  /* we need to heapify from the top, since that's where the leaf landed */
}
```

to actually sort the array.

Comment: "that check would be used if you have the top of the heap at index 1. For index 0, that should be < (also in the next check for r)" in which place I've to change < ?

Comment: In `if ((l <= heap_size)` and the corresponding line for `r`. Another thing is that once you start swapping the top of the heap in the last position, you need to call `heapify(0)` instead of `heapify(i)`, since the leaf got swapped to position 0.

Comment: Have you also changed the other things I mentioned?

Comment: I don't know in which way i can change this: "forgets to heapify the top, so it doesn't in general create a heap."

Comment: The loop condition there ought to be `i >= 0`.

Comment: now it works ;) i would like now update this program to sorting more than 5 arguments. Thank's.

Comment: Just pass the array and heap size as arguments to all your functions, then it works for arbitrary sizes.

Comment: how i can make a dynamic table - i would like to writ how big should it be? now i make in this way but i know that is wrong way :(

Comment: First, for all that's holy, make `heap_size` and the array _arguments_ of the functions. Don't use global variables if it's not absolutely necessary. Second, what about `malloc`? Just `malloc` what you need when you know how much you need.